# Java regex returns only single match

Tags: java, regex

I have file with content:

```
~LayerData
type="waypointlist"
type="waypointlistend"
type="track" name="Track1" color=#695cbb
type="trackpoint" latitude="43.5032064" longitude="16.4266248"
type="trackpoint" latitude="43.5071074767561" longitude="16.48329290000057"
type="trackend"
~EndLayerData
~LayerData
type="waypointlist"
type="waypointlistend"
type="track" name="Track2" color=#000000
type="trackpoint" latitude="43.51037193515589" longitude="16.491883500895977"
type="trackpoint" latitude="43.521582832754135" longitude="16.473187288140295"
type="trackend"
~EndLayerData
```

I'm extracing LayerData -> EndLayerData matches using:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(~LayerData(.|\n)*~EndLayerData)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
```

As a result I get m.group() with three items: first two are identical and contain the complete file. Last one is "\n". I expected to receive Track1 and Track2 separated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract here?

Comment: Remember to escape properly. a single `\` in a string becomes `\\`. `\n` is a line break, if you want to match it you need to use `\\n`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I'm trying to extract two LayerData sections

Comment: @Polygnome: This is copy-paste from IDE, there is \\ in source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match LayerData followed by all lines that do not start with either LayerData or EndLayerData using a negative lookahead.

```
^~LayerData(?:\R(?!~(?:End)?LayerData).*)*\R~EndLayerData
```

**Explanation**

- `^~LayerData` Match LayerData from the start of the string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\R(?!~(?:End)?LayerData)` Match a newline, assert what is directly to the right is not EndLayerData or LayerData
  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `)*` Close the group and repeat 0+ times to get all lines
- `\R~EndLayerData` Match a newline and EndLayerData

In Java with double escaped backslashes:

```
String regex = "^~LayerData(?:\\R(?!~(?:End)?LayerData).*)*\\R~EndLayerData";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBL0F6/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/9ra7Kb)

Example code

```
String regex = "^~LayerData(?:\\R(?!~(?:End)?LayerData).*)*\\R~EndLayerData";
String string = "...";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

`(~LayerData(.|\n)*?~EndLayerData)`

Comment: Thanks, but same result. The problem is that EndLayerData LayerData in the middle of file is not detected, not the LayerData content itself.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Use Code Generator under tools in regex101 to get language-specific regex.

```
String regex = "\\~LayerData(.|\\n)*?\\~EndLayerData";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string); 
while (matcher.find()) { 
System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

Earlier Answer:
You are not getting the match properly as the regex you are using is not proper. Since it matches with everything that starts with "~LayerData" and ends with "~EndLayerData", the whole file is getting matched. Creating an appropriate regex using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) (helps in visualizing) and using that should fix the issue.

Comment: This is the regex: https://regex101.com/r/JG3W09/1, but the problem here is setting the /g flag, which is enabled by default in Java, but the result is different, the on regex101.com

Comment: Not works, please take a look at online Java test: http://tpcg.io/cxW9uGRz

Comment: @ernest Works fine. Please take a look: http://tpcg.io/W3B7f1kd